# Update the converted lead record?

Tags: lead-conversion

I have to update some field of leads once it's converted.  However, salesforce make a lead read only once it's converted. Is there any way to update the lead record after converted ?  Thanks.

Comment: Only way to is update before conversion in a trigger i believe

Answer (score 1):

You can update in a before trigger prior to the conversion being completed.

Or maybe this link will help but it requires a lot more work and has a lot of caveats.

(Basically export, delete, reinsert setting system datetime fields to prior values.)

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000170793&language=en_US

Answer (score 1):

In [Spring 16](http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/spring16/release-notes/rn_sales_leads_edit_converted_leads.htm) you can now update leads after they have been converted. You will need to add the following permissions to your profile.

*User Permissions Needed
To update converted leads:

"Set Audit Fields upon Record Creation"
AND
"Update Records with Inactive Owners"*

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually, and by design, a converted Lead is like an archive.  The values in the Lead represent 'history' and values that can be altered in the future should be mapped to corresponding Account, Contact, and Opportunity records.

So, your business design/processes should not be built around converted Leads being changed.  The KB article mentioned by @Eric would be used for use cases where the historical data needed to be modified, perhaps for producing better reports on converted Leads where such historical data was incomplete or in error.